# How to use URL helper in Root.Master

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to set up this link in the Root.master file of my ASP.NET MVC project.  But the @ symbol is not recognized as razor syntax.  And the Action and Controller names are underlined in green with the message "Validation (HTML5): This attribute name must be followed by an equal sign and a value. If the value is in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match."  Does something need to be installed for the @Url to be used? Or do I need to achieve this a different way?  Thanks!

```
<a id="Link" href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")">Text</a>
```

Comment: You should give more information, but i would think you are using a wrong filetype - .html presumably. You need to use the .razor type...
By the way: what do you meen by "root master file"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a .NET Framework project.
Create a new .NET Core project to use razor @Url.Action.

Comment: That's not an option.  What would be an alternate way to achieve this within .Net Framework?